# Setting $PATH for weberver user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, environment-variables

I tried to add `$PATH` for all users including the webserver user (i.e. www-data) with different methods such as editing `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, etc. In all cases, it works in terminal, but not with shell commands within PHP.

For example `echo $PATH` in terminal shows available paths including that I added; but, `shell_exec('echo $PATH')` in PHP shows the original paths without the path I added:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

How can I set the $PATH globally to be usable by the webserver user? I am using nginx on Ubuntu/Debian.

I tried to edit `/etc/init.d/nginx`, I think this is the starting point for nginx, but no effect.

Comment: Does it work when using the www-data user in shell? (su -s www-data)

Comment: yes, in shell works (SSH terminal), but not when running as webserver users (executing shell commands in PHP). You mean `su - www-data`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say which distro but my guess is Ubuntu or similar.

The default PATH, defined in `/etc/init.d/apache2` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

On my Ubuntu systems there is a file `/etc/apache2/envvars`. You can define the `PATH` in this file and when you restart Apache that will be the path that is used.

```
PATH=$PATH:/your/addtional/path
```

---

For nginx you can pass the path that you want as a `fastcgi_param`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
    fastcgi_param PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/your/path;
}
```

You need to specify the whole PATH that you want

---

Further update.

I have php set up as fcgi so (thanks to @MichaelHampton for some chat discussion) and I found that the path that `system(...);` sees is the one set in your php init script (in my case /etc/init.d/php-fcgi).

---

And after much digging around I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/highload-php-en/PATH/highload-php-en/GIn5MEG7lgI/NHgOVQ7yzVwJ%5B1-25%5D) which leads to the solution

```
env[PATH]=/your/custom/path
```

in `php5-fpm.conf` or as @Ali points out in the `php5-fpm` start script.

Comment: You're quite right about Ubuntu, but I am using nginx. However, it is a useful hint.

Comment: I figured it out! `env[PATH]` in php5-fpm should be modified to include custom PATH. If you add this to your answer, I will set it as accepted answer. It is very useful to let others know that this should be set in PHP rather than nginx.

Comment: @Ali Ha! I just figured it out too :)

Comment: You can uncomment it in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Comment: Setting env[PATH] works. Now my shell_exec calls are working in PHP again.

Comment: +1 Setting `fastcgi_param PATH` doesn't work. Setting `env[PATH]` does. I think you should note that in your answer, so it's not the last thing that everybody tries. ;]